# Var needs to be a url link

Tags: php, variables

having a dumb and really "easy" issue with PHP I just want to make sure I'm correct

I need to have a variable that gonna format into an HTML href link pulling from the other 2 variables so my code looks like this

```
$varurl = <?php echo @$resVarurl["<a href=" + 'var_1' + '>' + 'var_2' ];?>
```

is that correct? or the best way to insert it?

the result would be something like $varurl =  var_2 title

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Best' is a subjective term, but there is no need to assign the variable `$varurl`, as you can simply inject the two variables into a string that gets output directly:

```
<?php echo "<a href='$var1'>$var2</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: i just need to assign that variable because it will be posted into a mysql table

Comment: but thank you alot, that already gave me an idea how to proceed!